# Qual é a utilidade de saber depurar um código em R?

Tags: r, debug

Segundo a [teoria](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html), *debugging* pode ser definido como *a arte e a ciência de corrigir problemas inesperados em seu código*.

- Qual é a utilidade (para um analista de dados) de saber *debugar* um código?
- Quais funções existem em `R` para fazer isso?

Comment: Corrigir problemas  em seu código.

Comment: Isto é importante para um analista de dados? Muitos conceitos em `R` tem maior relevância para quem desenvolve *packages*, como *escopo léxico* e *escopo dinâmico*.

Comment: O que seria isso que você chama de "Analista de dados"? Está se referindo ao profissional que analisa e compila dados para tomada de decisões dentro de uma empresa? Ou está se referindo ao Analista de Sistemas?

Comment: *"ao profissional que analisa e compila dados para tomada de decisões dentro de uma empresa"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Qual é a utilidade (para um analista de dados) de saber debugar um
>   código?

Em geral "debuggar" ou depurar um código tem a finalidade de checar se uma ou mais funcionalidades da aplicação ao serem executadas tem o comportamento desejado, ou seja, verificar se todas as condições por mais implícitas que sejam foram checadas, tratar possíveis bugs e falhas de maneira adequada e claro, verificar se a lógica de negócios da aplicação está sendo executada de maneira correta.

Saber utilizar da depuração para um profissional cuja função é analisar os dados é essencial para verificar a integridade dos dados coletados e também checar se as funções que geram resultados que serão levados em conta para a análise estão programadas com a lógica correta.

---

> Quais funções existem em R para fazer isso?

**Sem uma IDE**

Existe a função `browser()`, ela irá pausar o código quando o código é executado em modo de depuração.
Quando isso ocorrer,você pode digitar nome de variáveis que seriam acessíveis naquele escopo para verificar o valor delas.
Para execução em modo de depuração via console é só digitar `debugSource("<NomeDoArquivo>")`.

**Com uma IDE (RStudio)**

Você pode delimitar um *break point* clicando na área à esquerda do código, quando isso ocorrer, um ponto vermelho ficará marcado no início da linha e terá o mesmo comportamento da função `browser()`, só irá pausar a execução do código quando o código for executado em modo de depuração.

Para executar em modo de depuração no RStudio é só checar a opção "*Source on Save*" e salvar o código, clicar em "*Source*" na parte superior direita do RStudio ou apertar `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`S`.

Answer (score 4):

Para um analista de dados é importante. Pois dependendo da sua função, é através dos dados obtidos pelo sistema que é gerado o valor para o negócio da empresa. Como por exemplo, algumas empresas hoje atuam muito com mineração de dados e com leads, então é necessário que o analista de dados conheça bem o seu sistema.

Não tenho muito conhecimento em R, mas é uma linguagem muito utilizada para estatísticas, pois possui funções como por exemplo RSiteSearch(), que permite pesquisar palavras chaves no parâmetro passado a ela!

Answer (score 4):

Não conheço a linguagem R mas, falarei do debbug como um todo.

O debbug em si, independente de ser para análise de dados, quanto para um código de sistema web, você saber debugar seu código, ajuda no sentido de voce poder acompanhar passo a passo o percurso e as mudanças que o dado tem em seu sistema, facilitando assim a chance de você corrigir erros não observados durante o desenvolvimento, e até achar falhas de códigos faltantes em seu sistema.

Bom o debbug é uma ferramenta muito poderosa seja ela para qual finalidade for o desenvolvimento, eu encorajo a todos que desenvolvem qualquer tipo de sistema, para qualquer tipo de solução a usar o debbug durante seu processo de desenvolvimento, pois assim você pode economizar muito tempo tentando achar um erro de uma funcionalidade apenas analisando o código a olho nu.

Espero ter dado uma ideia da importância de saber debugar um código, independentemente da problema que o código venha resolver.

Answer (score 4):

Não tenho conhecimento na linguagem R.

Um analista de dados que saiba depurar (ou debugar) um código faz seu trabalho em menos tempo, gerando menos despesa e um produto mais eficiente.

Muitos dos erros não são detectados pelas linguagens de programação, não geram exceções e o código é executado, apresentando dados e informações incorretas. Para resolver isto, é possível criar funções, pequenos trechos de código ou usar bibliotecas especializadas para sinalizar o problema, forçando uma interrupção (parada) e mostrando uma mensagem.

Conforme https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Debugging (em inglês), seguem algumas funções úteis:

```
traceback()
debugger
debugger.look()
## it turns warnings into errors
options(warn = 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Boa tarde Giovani,

**- O que é *debugging*?**

Em linha gerais podemos dizer que *debugar* ou *depurar*, tratando-se de programas, é a ação de remover anomalias e/ou *bugs* que distorcem a veracidade e/ou integridade dos seus dados, erros esses que não foram previstos pelos desenvolvedores do mesmo. O compilador ou IDE que você esteja trabalhando é capaz de detectar erros de sintaxe, execução ou bibliotecas não importadas por exemplo, mas isso não garante que suas variáveis não vão assumir valores estranhos durante a execução, a final, [merda acontece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shit_happens)[*English*].

> O *debugging* é uma boa prática para garantir a qualidade dos
>   *softwares* produzidos.

Ao depurar um código você pode ir acompanhando o passo a passo da execução através dos *breakpoints*, verificando quais as funções estão sendo chamadas, que valores as variáveis estão assumindo, qual valor seus testes retornam, dentre outras coisas, tudo isso a fim de procurar de forma mais eficiente em qual ponto da execução sua lógica está errada.

**- Qual é a utilidade, para um analista de dados, de saber debugar um código?**

Nesse ponto chegamos em uma questão delicada, pois a partir daqui tudo vai depender de como é a sua realidade dentro da organização empresarial, a final, **nem todo analista de dados precisa necessariamente saber programar** já que **pode** se tratar de uma função de analisar dados, e não produzi-los, que é o caso de gerentes de lojas, por exemplo. Através de relatórios de vendas eles podem perceber o que está vendendo mais e o que não está, e a partir disso tomar suas decisões de negócios. Veja que no exemplo citado não é necessário que o gerente saiba programar, ainda que ele se utilize da programação para seu trabalho.

Por outro lado, se o seu trabalho inclui a produção desses dados, é de fundamental importância que você saiba depurar o código para garantir a integridade e veracidade dos dados para a partir deles sejam tomadas as melhores decisões para sua empresa. Voltando para o exemplo citado: Se as informações desse relatório não são verídicas de alguma forma, esse gerente vai tomar decisões a partir de informações falsas e, por consequência, pode prejudicar seu negócio.

Não conheço as ferramentas para *debugging* em `R`, porém achei esse link: [Depurando código em R](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/rtvs/debugging-r-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017), espero que lhe seja útil.

Abraços!